# Return the lines in which the numbers are

Tags: c++, linux, loops, grep

I have next file with thousands of lines

1 2 3 4
1 4 5
6
5 6 8 9
5
2 4 7 9
5 8 10
1 3 5 9
.......

Each line (the line number represents the regions) has maximum 4 values  (represent labels) and these values are between 0 and 1000.

And I want to know in which lines (regions) are the values (labels) and order them, for that I will need a loop but I do not how. 
For instance for the label number 1 is found in line (region) 1,2 and 8 so the output must be 1: 1 2 8

I want this output:
1: 1 2 8
2: 1 6
3: 1 8
4: 1 2 6
5: 2 4 5 7 8
6: 3 4
7: 6
8: 4 7
9: 4 6 8
10: 7
....
The output is the sorted labels from 0 to 1000 and the regions in which they are found. 
I was thinking in a loop in Linux or c++ any idea?

Comment: `std::array<std::vector<int>, 1001>` may help.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `std::map<int, std::list<int>>` that maps `int` to `list<int>`.
For each value use:

```
auto iter = map.find(row);
if (iter != m.end() )
{
    (iter->second).push_back(val);
} else {
    map[row] = std::list<int>(1, val);
}
```

Then use an `iterator` and print all the key,value pairs at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -lne 'push @{ $h{$_} }, $. for split
           }{
           print "$_: @{ $h{$_} }" for sort { $a <=> $b } keys %h
          ' < input.txt
```

`$.` is the line number, you just add it to the hash table for each of the numbers on the line. At the end, you sort the keys of the hash table numerically and print the corresponding arrays.